# What is this hidden directory doing on my Desktop?

Tags: macos, file-permissions, chmod

On my Mac I just encountered a hidden directory on my desktop. I don't recall putting it there.

When I type `ls -la` in Terminal on the desktop I get the following:

[image]

The last folder is what triggered my attention. It is also highlighted.
When I `cd` into that directory and type `ls -la` I see:

```
total 16
drwxrwxrwx@  4 user  staff  136 Oct 18  2012 .
drwx---rwx  17 user  staff  578 Dec 17 15:03 ..
-rw-rw-rw-@  1 user  staff  231 Jan 16  2013 6VR16NQEUJ456542VDR66LS7
-rw-rw-rw-@  1 user  staff  226 May  8  2013 K7wuT15oKsg=
```

The `6VR...` file can be opened in Sublime Text as a Hex file, the other shows up empty.
What is this folder doing on my desktop? Googling the exact name does not give any results.

Comment: The green highlighting is just a way of showing that the rights are set to 777 (drwxrwxrwx). I don't know of a "sticky" type of file or folder.

Comment: That is very well possible. I googled this highlighting and stumbled on the sticky term. Might have misunderstood that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a file or folder is highlighted, it means that file has the read, write, and execute permissions set for Owner, Group, and Other (chmod 777). The folder is not a "sticky" folder.

For Mac OSX a sticky bit is designated in the "EXECUTE" (x) bit within the file or directory properties.

For example:

`drwtrwxrwx`

Breaking down the above line:

d = directory

rwt = The OWNER of the file has read, write, and is the only one who has permissions to delete this file (oh and execute)

rwx = Any user part of the GROUP "staff" which you kindly displayed above in your example has the power to read, write, and execute.

the last rwx = anyone not part of the group staff and not an owner has the right to read, write, and execute.

That directory could've been created possibly by a program, someone hijacking your machine, etc. There could be any number of reasons that was placed there.

I'd advise deleting it and if you'd like perform a scan on your machine.

Check to see if your machine has any ports open for listening using `netstat -antp` in terminal.

Comment: Deleted it (I have a Timemachine backup just in case), ran a scan with ClamXav (clean) and found 8 listening ports. 6 of them I could trace down to legitimate processes (Dropbox, some plugin listening for uploads, etc...) Two other ports `127.0.0.1.631` and `::1.631` (are these the same only for IPv4/v6?) did not show anything when used with `losf -i :portnumber`

Comment: Should be fine then. It was most likely a program you previously installed and ran that created the directory.

Answer (score 0):

The first one `.` is the hidden folder filesystems use to identify the current directory (remember that the way to run a script in your current working directory is `./blah`).

The second could have gotten there any number of ways, some of them malicious. Run a scan on your machine, but don't delete it right away because it might have been put there by a legitimate program.